# flatiron-director / core-pages SPA with route specific js functions & default route

Tags: polymer

i am working with flatiron-director and core-pages. my question is how would i set a default route? also how do i call js functions on specific routes.

my code looks something like this

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <flatiron-director id='page-director' route="{{route}}" 
                   autoHash on-director-route="{{routeChanged}}"></flatiron-director>

    <core-menu id="menu">
      <paper-item icon="list" label="1">
        <a href="#1"></a>
      </paper-item>
      <paper-item icon="swap-vert" label="2">
        <a href="#2"></a>
      </paper-item>
      <paper-item icon="file-download" label="3">
        <a href="#3"></a>
      </paper-item>
    </core-menu>

    <core-pages selected="{{route}}"  valueattr="page">
      <div page="1">
        //page 1
      </div>
      <div page="2">
        // page 2
      </div>
      <div page="3">
        //page 3
      </div>
    </core-pages>

</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This app sets a default route and should demonstrate what you want: http://polymer-change.appspot.com/demos/spa.html.

I believe the relevant code would be:

```
var template = document.querySelector('template');

template.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
  this.route = this.route || 1; // default route to "1".
});
```

Comment: thank you sir. i knew i was over looking something in that document.