# How to use Polymer's paper-tabs

Tags: html, web, polymer, material-design

I'm just begin using Polymer to design my web, and I have some trouble with it.

Take a look at this: 
http://zirox.freevnn.com/newMaterialdesign.html

I want to switch to another site when I tab/click the tab's name.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Please post the code in the question.

Comment: it sounds like you will want to look into using core-pages or core-animated-pages. https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-pages or https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages  also you might want to look @ this post i made a while back on making a polymer spa. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454926/flatiron-director-core-pages-spa-with-route-specific-js-functions-default-ro

Answer (score -1):

You should connect it with core-pages. then on the page-change event you also change the select value of  core-page element. You have just one page so there is nothing to change to.